# How to find local maximum of this summation

Tags: optimization, vectors

I have $\mathbf{n}_0$ normal vector. I want to find another normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ near $\mathbf{n}_0$ that results in the following summation being at a local maximum. $\mathbf{bold}$ variables are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. $\mathbf{c}$ is a known constant vector. It doesn't have to be the nearest nor the global maximum, just one of the nearer local maximum.

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n||(\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{c}) - ((\mathbf{p}_i-\mathbf{c})\cdot\mathbf{n})*\mathbf{n}|| $$

I will be using this in a computer algorithm.

Comment: I assume $p_i$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and that $((p_i-c)\cdot n)*n$ is multiplication of $n$ by the inner product between $(p_i-c)$ and $n$. Then the sum you wrote is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What do you mean by a local maximum of this vector?

Comment: @uniquesolution Oops, sorry about that. I fixed it. I added taking the magnitude.